# Access sharepoint from asp.net site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, asp.net, host-header

This is my senario,

I have Sharepoint 2010/2016 environment and asp.net site. Everything is on windows authentication. I would like to access sharepoint 2010/2016 from my asp.net site.

Here are few questions,

- is this possible ?
- if yes then how can i configure my environment so that i can access sharepoint from asp.net site from code behind
- if yes then how can i configure my environment so that i can access it from JavaScript (directly from browser)

Hope i was able to put my question with enough details.

Comment: What type of access would you require from asp.net? To read/add to SharePoint list items? If yes, you could utilize SharePoint APIs (CSOM for code behind and JSOM for javascript).

Answer (score 1):

If your asp.net page is not on same server as of SharePoint then you can use CSOM to access SharePoint fromyour asp.net ( on different server) 
[here](https://dev.office.com/sharepoint/docs/sp-add-ins/complete-basic-operations-using-sharepoint-client-library-code)!